# Typescript declaration merging library types

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

does somebody know how to "extend" (via declaration merging) the declarations of interfaces, that where declared in a library file from typescript?

In my case i want to extend the interface **HTMLCanvasElement** of the typescript build in library **lib.dom**. I know how declaration merging is working but i don't get the right imports for the interface HTMLCanvasElement.

```js
import {HTMLCanvasElement} from '<what.to.use.here>';

declare module '<what.to.use.here>'{
    interface HTMLCanvasElement{
        //add my stuff
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those types live in the global namespace. If you are in a script file (ie not a module) you can just redeclare it. If you are in a module, you need to declare it in `global` no import required.

```
declare global{
    interface HTMLCanvasElement{
        my:number
    }
}

export var x = 1;// just to make this module
let c: HTMLCanvasElement;
c.animate // regular stuff 
c.my //my stuff
```